# Is there a way, in QGIS, with an expression, to convert a color to hexadecimal value?

Tags: qgis, convert, expression, color

Is there a way, in QGIS, with an expression, to convert a color to hexadecimal value?
Or eventually to convert an integer to hexadecimal
like
`to_hex(255) → FF`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct function to convert from decimal to hex using QGIS expressions afaik. But using some math, you can create an expression that does the job.

The following expression works for numbers from 0 to 255 (see below for larger numbers and at the bottom for converting RGBA to HEX colors). Define your input in decimal number in line 3 and the expression calculates the hexadecimal value:

```
with_variable(
    'numb',
    255,  -- decimal number to convert
with_variable(
    'hex',
    array_cat( 
        generate_series(0,9),
        array('A','B','C','D','E','F')
    ),
@hex [floor (@numb/16)] || 
@hex [@numb%16]))
```

[image]

For numbers larger than 255 (but including 0 to 255), use this adapted version of the expression. It seems to work reliably up to input numbers of size +/- 10^15 (tested with https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html) what should be enough for most cases; for larger values, it outputs a message asking for a number inside the range:

```
with_variable(
    'numb',
    255,  -- decimal number to convert, not larger than +/- 10^15 (1000000000000000)
with_variable(
    'hex',
    array_cat (generate_series(0,9), array('A','B','C','D','E','F')),
case 
when 
    @numb between -10^15 and 10^15
then if (@numb<0,'-','') || 
    ltrim( 
        array_to_string(
            array_append (
                array_foreach (
                    generate_series (
                        array_length (
                            array_filter (
                                array_foreach (
                                    generate_series (0,100),
                                    abs(@numb)/16^@element
                                ),
                                @element > 1
                            )
                        )-0,
                        1,
                        -1
                    ),
                    @hex [floor (abs(@numb)/(16^@element))%16] 
                ),
                @hex [abs(@numb)%16]
            ),
            ''
        ),'0'
    )
else    'Enter a number between -10^15 and 10^15'
end
))
```

---

And finally, as mentioned in the comment by @Charles, the OP of this question, based on the above expression you can convert RGBA (from a field `"colors"`) to HEX using this expression (made a bit shorter by using `array_foreach()` for each RGBA value):

```
with_variable(
    'hex', 
    array_cat(
        generate_series(0,9),
        array('A','B','C','D','E','F')
    ), 
    array_to_string (
        array_foreach (
            array ('red','green','blue','alpha'),
            with_variable(
                'colo',
                color_part (@symbol_color,@element),
                @hex[floor(@colo/16)] || @hex[@colo%16] 
            )
        ),''
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. With your help I achieved to convert RGBA (from a field "colors") to HEX:
`with_variable('hex', array_cat(generate_series(0,9),   array('A','B','C','D','E','F') ),
with_variable('red', color_part("colors" ,'red'),
with_variable('green', color_part("colors" ,'green'),
with_variable('blue', color_part("colors" ,'blue'),
with_variable('alpha', color_part("colors" ,'alpha'),
@hex[floor(@red/16)] || 
@hex[@red%16]
||
@hex[floor(@green/16)] || 
@hex[@green%16]
||
@hex[floor(@blue/16)] || 
@hex[@blue%16]
||
@hex[floor(@alpha/16)] || 
@hex[@alpha%16]
)))))
`

Comment: Thanks @Charles, I added that at the bottom of the solution: a bit shortened form to avoid repeating the similar parts over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for the shortening. I inverted alpha and blue by mistake in my solution by the way .

Comment: why do you mean? The correct order is rgba, right? that's exactly what I can see in your comment...?

Comment: Yes but in hexadecimal the order is ARGB. I can't edit my comment.